# Separate Categories from WC Product loop when display type is set to both on the category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In our site we used to display categories and products in different separate sections when display type was set to `'both'` using `woocommerce_product_subcategories()` function.

I have recently updated woocommerce to the latest `v3.4.3` and found out that the function `woocommerce_product_subcategories()` has been deprecated. Now they have introduced different functions to display categories, like `woocommerce_output_product_categories()`, `woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories()`.

But the problem I'm having is that, I could not stop showing categories in product loop. It keeps showing both categories and products in the same loop.

Can anyone show me a way, how I can display categories and products in a separate section?

**EDIT**

To clarify my question, in my category settings, display type is set to both.

[image: category setting]

When I'm browsing category archive page, both category and products are showing in the loop.

[image]

What I want, is to separate categories from the loop and show it in a different section. In the loop, I want to display only products.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Did you customize the WooCommerce shop pages? Did you use filters/actions to filter the WooCommerce results?

Details are needed before anyone can really be of any assistance.

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope this will simplify to understand the problem.

Comment: The screenshot 'Display Type' is either a) a very old version of WooCommerce, b) a theme control, or c) a custom plugin. But it is definitely not native WooCommerce.

Without knowing what theme or plugin you are using there isn't much we can do to help.

Comment: It is actually native to WC. Only plugin active is WooCommerce, and I'm using Storefront theme. Everything is updated to its latest version.

Comment: Not native WooCommerce, a Storefront theme control. You'll have to work with WooCommerce support to address the issue.

Comment: It is in fact native to WC. I have activated other themes like TwentySeventeen, ThentyFifteen. And the settings still showing. Moreover, I believe the code is written, in WC filename, `woocommerce/include/admin/class-wc-admin-taxonomies.php` line number 203.

Comment: I stand corrected, your screenshot is of the categories page, not the global WooCoomerece settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79813/discussion-between-arif-and-steve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution I was looking for. Using the following code will stop displaying categories in the product loop.

`remove_filter( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', 'woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories' );`

Then use the following function in a separate section of the page will render the categories in a separate section.
`woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories()`

Comment: I found a good tutorial how to display product categories on a different way: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/display-woocommerce-categories-subcategories-and-products-in-separate-lists--cms-25479

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Arif answer.

In function.php

```
// remove the subcategories from the product loop
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', 'woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories' );

// add subcategories before the product loop (yet after catalog_ordering and result_count -> see priority 40)
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'wp56123_show_product_subcategories', 40 );

function wp56123_show_product_subcategories() {
    $subcategories = woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories();
        if ($subcategories) {
          echo '<ul class="subcategories">',$subcategories,'</ul>';
    }
}
```

Tested on Woocommerce 3.9

Comment: Faced the same problem. Solution from Vanois.be works, till I apply filter based on taxonomies. Than I recieved duplicated output based on applied filter.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/display-categories-in-woocommerce/). It is updated to the latest version of Woocommerce (3.6).

The tutorial on [Tutsplus](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/display-woocommerce-categories-subcategories-and-products-in-separate-lists--cms-25479) is great but no longer up to date.